# Random images on load in this slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, random, slider

I've got this slider from codepen, and I wanted to showcase some work on it later, for example the first slide will be 'Photography' next one can be 'Illustrations' and so on.

I want to have 3 images that are random chosen on each refresh (I have now one that shows but there are 2 other written in comment in HTML).

Here is my code.

```js
let dots = 4;
let sliderElem = document.querySelector(".slider");
let dotElems = sliderElem.querySelectorAll(".slider__dot");
let indicatorElem = sliderElem.querySelector(".slider__indicator");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(dotElems, dotElem => {
 dotElem.addEventListener("click", e => {
  let currentPos = parseInt(sliderElem.getAttribute("data-pos"));
  let newPos = parseInt(dotElem.getAttribute("data-pos"));

  let newDirection = newPos > currentPos ? "right" : "left";
  let currentDirection = newPos < currentPos ? "right" : "left";

  indicatorElem.classList.remove(`slider__indicator--${currentDirection}`);
  indicatorElem.classList.add(`slider__indicator--${newDirection}`);
  sliderElem.setAttribute("data-pos", newPos);
 });
});
```

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider__slides {
  position: relative;
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1);
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1);
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1), -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1);
  will-change: transform;
}
.slider[data-pos="0"] .slider__slides {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
          transform: translateX(0%);
}
.slider[data-pos="1"] .slider__slides {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-25%);
          transform: translateX(-25%);
}
.slider[data-pos="2"] .slider__slides {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.slider[data-pos="3"] .slider__slides {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-75%);
          transform: translateX(-75%);
}
.slider__slide {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slider__slide img {
  width:50%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.slider__dots {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1.5em;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.slider__dot, .slider__indicator {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 100px;
}
.slider__indicator {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  width: auto;
}
.slider__indicator--left {
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1.15), right 0.3s 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1.15);
  transition: left 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1.15), right 0.3s 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1.15);
}
.slider__indicator--right {
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1.15), right 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1.15);
  transition: left 0.3s 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1.15), right 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1.15);
}
.slider[data-pos="0"] .slider__indicator {
  left: 0em;
  right: 6em;
}
.slider[data-pos="1"] .slider__indicator {
  left: 2em;
  right: 4em;
}
.slider[data-pos="2"] .slider__indicator {
  left: 4em;
  right: 2em;
}
.slider[data-pos="3"] .slider__indicator {
  left: 6em;
  right: 0em;
}

.center {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  background: #333;
}

.slider {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.slider__slide:nth-child(1) {
  background: #309954;
}
.slider__slide:nth-child(2) {
  background: #FFBD3C;
}
.slider__slide:nth-child(3) {
  background: #F8593E;
}
.slider__slide:nth-child(4) {
  background: #4086FA;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
 
 <div class="slider" data-pos="0">
  <div class="slider__slides">
   <div class="slider__slide">
     <img src="http://www.dogster.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/google-dog-search-2014-05.jpg">
        
        <!-- Second image that has a chance of showing upload load
        <img src="http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/569fdd9ac08a80bd448b7138/google-is-officially-a-dog-company.jpg">
      -->
      
      <!-- Third
        <img src="http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/569fdd9ac08a80bd448b7138/google-is-officially-a-dog-company.jpg">
      -->
        
        
        
        
   </div>
   <div class="slider__slide"></div>
   <div class="slider__slide"></div>
   <div class="slider__slide"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__dots">
   <a href="#" class="slider__indicator"></a>
   <a href="#" class="slider__dot" data-pos="0"></a>
   <a href="#" class="slider__dot" data-pos="1"></a>
   <a href="#" class="slider__dot" data-pos="2"></a>
   <a href="#" class="slider__dot" data-pos="3"></a>
  </div>
 </div>
 
</div>
```

I **beleive** in order to have the random images I need to have a var saved in javascript this way, is that correct?

```
 var imgs = [
        'http://www.dogster.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/google-dog-search-2014-05.jpg',
        'http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/569fdd9ac08a80bd448b7138/google-is-officially-a-dog-company.jpg',
        'http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/569fdd9ac08a80bd448b7138/google-is-officially-a-dog-company.jpg'
    ];
```

To get a **random** one:

```
var img_index = Math.floor( Math.random()*imgs.length );
```

But how do I know **integrate this in HTML?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to change the initial position of the slider after every refresh.

Your idea was in the right direction with the `Math.random` use.

I have modified your code a little bit adding `sliderElem.setAttribute("data-pos", Math.floor(Math.random() * dots));` to your Javascript code. This will set the initial position of the slider when the Javascript file loads.

I have also filled the slider component with the images you suggested.

### Edit

I have changed the code to randomize the image at the first slide. That slide now have an `id="first-slide` to make it more easy to find.
As you can see, now there is a function `getRandomImage()` that returns the URL of a random image.

You can add more images to the `imgs` array and the function will continue selecting a random one from the complete array.

I have also changed the rounding function from `Math.floor` to `Math.round` to give the last image more chances of appearing.

```js
let dots = 4;
let sliderElem = document.querySelector(".slider");
let dotElems = sliderElem.querySelectorAll(".slider__dot");
let indicatorElem = sliderElem.querySelector(".slider__indicator");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(dotElems, dotElem => {
  dotElem.addEventListener("click", e => {
    let currentPos = parseInt(sliderElem.getAttribute("data-pos"));
    let newPos = parseInt(dotElem.getAttribute("data-pos"));

    let newDirection = newPos > currentPos ? "right" : "left";
    let currentDirection = newPos < currentPos ? "right" : "left";

    indicatorElem.classList.remove(`slider__indicator--${currentDirection}`);
    indicatorElem.classList.add(`slider__indicator--${newDirection}`);
    sliderElem.setAttribute("data-pos", newPos);
  });
});

function getRandomImage() {
  let imgs = ['http://www.dogster.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/google-dog-search-2014-05.jpg', 'http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/569fdd9ac08a80bd448b7138/google-is-officially-a-dog-company.jpg'];
  let pos = Math.round(Math.random() * (imgs.length - 1));
  return imgs[pos];
}

document.getElementById('first-slide').setAttribute('src', getRandomImage());
/* Uncomment the line below to randomize slider initial position */
// sliderElem.setAttribute("data-pos", Math.floor(Math.random() * dots));
```

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider__slides {
  position: relative;
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1);
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1);
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1), -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1);
  will-change: transform;
}
.slider[data-pos="0"] .slider__slides {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
          transform: translateX(0%);
}
.slider[data-pos="1"] .slider__slides {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-25%);
          transform: translateX(-25%);
}
.slider[data-pos="2"] .slider__slides {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.slider[data-pos="3"] .slider__slides {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-75%);
          transform: translateX(-75%);
}
.slider__slide {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slider__slide img {
  width:50%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.slider__dots {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1.5em;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.slider__dot, .slider__indicator {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 100px;
}
.slider__indicator {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  width: auto;
}
.slider__indicator--left {
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1.15), right 0.3s 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1.15);
  transition: left 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1.15), right 0.3s 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1.15);
}
.slider__indicator--right {
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1.15), right 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1.15);
  transition: left 0.3s 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1.15), right 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.51, 0.92, 0.24, 1.15);
}
.slider[data-pos="0"] .slider__indicator {
  left: 0em;
  right: 6em;
}
.slider[data-pos="1"] .slider__indicator {
  left: 2em;
  right: 4em;
}
.slider[data-pos="2"] .slider__indicator {
  left: 4em;
  right: 2em;
}
.slider[data-pos="3"] .slider__indicator {
  left: 6em;
  right: 0em;
}

.center {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  background: #333;
}

.slider {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.slider__slide:nth-child(1) {
  background: #309954;
}
.slider__slide:nth-child(2) {
  background: #FFBD3C;
}
.slider__slide:nth-child(3) {
  background: #F8593E;
}
.slider__slide:nth-child(4) {
  background: #4086FA;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="slider" data-pos="0">
    <div class="slider__slides">
      <div class="slider__slide">
        <img id="first-slide" src="http://www.dogster.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/google-dog-search-2014-05.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__slide">
        <img src="http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/569fdd9ac08a80bd448b7138/google-is-officially-a-dog-company.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__slide">
        <img src="http://www.dogster.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/google-dog-search-2014-05.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slider__slide">
        <img src="http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/569fdd9ac08a80bd448b7138/google-is-officially-a-dog-company.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__dots">
      <a href="#" class="slider__indicator"></a>
      <a href="#" class="slider__dot" data-pos="0"></a>
      <a href="#" class="slider__dot" data-pos="1"></a>
      <a href="#" class="slider__dot" data-pos="2"></a>
      <a href="#" class="slider__dot" data-pos="3"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I actually wanted to change one of the three pics on the first slide randomly at load, don't mind the other 3 slides

Comment: @Panic I have modified the code. Now it selects a random image for the first slide only. See the edit comment for more info

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the job

Comment: @ David Harillo Sánchez Is there some way to fix it that it doesn't show the previous picture on load?  I mean sometimes I need to reload my page 3 times to get another image because the math random gets lucky and goes for the same number 3 times which makes it look like the code is broken/buggy to people who don't have a clue how it works. Thanks for all the input and effort, greatly appreciated!!

Comment: @Panic you will need to use cookies for something like that. Then you could store the last position shown to that user and when the page reloads, you show the next image in the array instead of it being random.
Another option is make the array of images big enough (10 images maybe?) to reduce the chance of showing the same image two times in a row. But the chance will still be there